# How to match an index of a CSS class with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, class, selector

I want to match the index of a CSS class.

**Example:**

Given string: `.item.item-3.layer.layer-1.test`

Desired result: `3` (the index following the class "item")

But my current RegEx just gives me the index of the last class with a dash:

```
var matches = destinationClass.match(/[^-]+$/);
console.log(matches[0]);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var matches = destinationClass.match(/item-([0-9]+)/);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

matches[1] gives the substring corresponding the part of pattern enclosed in parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your regex to:

```
match(/item-([0-9]+)/).pop()
```

Comment: But then it grabs "item-3" but I just want to have the "3".

Comment: Then add `.pop()` to the end

Comment: Thanks. To use pop() is very smart. Thank you very much! :)